# normal subgroups: proving $H\lhd D_8$, given $K \ntriangleleft D_8$, knowing $KH$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was asked to prove $H\lhd$$D_8$, given that K$\ntriangleleft$$D_8$. But later in the same problem I am suppose to prove that $HK\lhd$$D_8$.

I thought that if $H\lhd$$D_8$ and $K\lhd$$D_8$ then $HK\lhd$$D_8$

I was given this to work with 
$D_8$ ={$1,r, r^2, r^3,b,br,br^2,br^3$}, $H$={$1,r^2$}

And given $KH$={$1,r^2,b,br^2$}

Any thoughts or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no contradiction in your problem.  Just because the product of two normal subgroups is normal does not mean that a normal subgroup times a non-normal subgroup cannot be normal.

Answer (score 2):

"If $H\lhd$$D_8$ and $K\lhd$$D_8$ then $HK\lhd$$D_8$" doesn't contradicts $H\lhd D_8$,$K\ntriangleleft D_8$ and $HK\lhd D_8$.

In general if $P\land R\rightarrow Q$ is true, $P\land Q\land \lnot R$ can be true.